# H2O features transformations inside MOJO models

Tags: h2o

I'm checking how we can use H2O MOJO models to run scoring models at prod using java api. I've received MOJO model in zip file from data scientists teams and managed to produce some predictions. Now I have a question will it be possible for data scientists to apply transformations on features (data set) which was used by model. Assume they will be not able to use data set as is and simple transformations will be required.

Answer (score 2):

Take a looks at the Sparkling Water project. You can build pipelines where the data preprocessing is performed by a logic written in Spark and ML performed by H2O-3 models.

- https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.3/latest-stable/doc/about.html
- https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.3/latest-stable/doc/deployment/load_mojo.html
- https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thanks, but as I see in example it is step outside of model. So, it will require to build additional process how data scientist can deliver those steps. Assume not many data scientists will be able to deliver java code.

Comment: With SW, you can train the pipeline that contains data munging steps and h2o-3 algorithm. You can do that with Scala or Python API. Or you can fit h2o-3 model separately, download mojo artifact, [load mojo to SW](https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.3/latest-stable/doc/deployment/load_mojo.html) and plug the mojo model stage into a pipeline with preprocessing steps. This should cover users of R API, but you will duplicate the preprocessing/data munging logic.

Comment: Our analytics saying it's not possible to integrate munging steps into MOJO zip file, but they can generate Transformer java class. Maybe it will be possible to use in our standard spark ETL jobs. At this stage we experimenting with standard spark and H2O libraries inside spark reading MOJO models in Hadoop environment. SW looks like more complex config, where experts prefer to use together with H2O instance and data transfer between spark and instance. I will try to check also SW variant.